# Matrix representation of a reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Assume I have a vector $v =$  $(-1, 1, -1)^T$ and $A$ is the relection through the plane orthogonal to $v$. 
How would I find the matrix representation of A? 

I have in my notes that the general formula of a reflection is 
$A = $$I - 2(\frac{x.x^{T}}{x^{T}.x})$ and I know the inner product of orthogonal vectors is $0$, but I'm not sure how to do this question.

Comment: The plane of symmetry passes through (0,0,0)?

Comment: You just state the formula you just stated, but with $x = v$. Are you looking for a proof that this formula works? Or was that all you needed?

Comment: @TheoBendit I misunderstood the formula, it was way easier than I thought. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see. No worries!